# Creating squared halo instead of circular in TileMill?

Tags: shapefile, tilemill

Is it possible to style a halo around text that has a square shape instead of a circle? If not, what are the alternatives to make a "halo" around number angular, in a shape of a square? Software I am using is TILEMILL. On this picture below i posted, you can see blue circle around number which is halo. I don't want for a that blue halo to be a circle but a square instead.
[image]

Comment: I do not believe that halo is right method for you. You should define shields for your address numbers. I do not know how to do that but try to find how the shields for the highway numbers have been done http://www.openstreetmap.org/#map=12/-6.7870/39.1343.  BTW. you could have edited your previous question instead of making a new one.